# Show table when radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

At first, I request you to see these two images.
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtUZY.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXtIF.png)

There are more than 20 fields like in 'Image 1'. If select yes then show a table like in 'Image 2'. So I have 20 Yes/No field and 20 different tables.
How can I show the tables if select yes. I have tried some code for a single field. As there are lots of fields I want to know is there any way to make the code minimal and easier. Here is my code that I tried:

CSS:

```
#show-dc-table {
  display: none;
}
```

Script:

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-check-inline input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'allergy-yes') {
      $('#show-dc-table').show();
    } else {
      $('#show-dc-table').hide();
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Do you have Allergies </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="allergy" value="Yes" id="allergy-yes">
      <label class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="allergy" value="No">
      <label class="form-check-label">No</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped" id="show-dc-table">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Alergic Reactions to</th>
    <th scope="col">Yes</th>
    <th scope="col">No</th>
    <th scope="col">Notes</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the same code work for multiple repeated HTML structures group elements by behaviour using the same class on each. Then use DOM traversal to relate the elements to each other when certain events happen.

In your case you would use `closest()` and `next()` to find the `table` related to the changed radio. Also note that you should use the `checked` property of the radio, along with the `change` event, to determine the value selected. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-check-inline input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('.form-group').next('table').toggle(this.checked && this.value === 'Yes');
  });
});
```

```css
.show-dc-table {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Do you have allergies?</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="allergy" value="Yes">
      <label class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="allergy" value="No">
      <label class="form-check-label">No</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped show-dc-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Alergic Reactions to</th>
      <th scope="col">Yes</th>
      <th scope="col">No</th>
      <th scope="col">Notes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Aspirin, Ibuprofen, Codeine</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="a1" /></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="a2" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Do you have a cough?</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="cough" value="Yes">
      <label class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="cough" value="No">
      <label class="form-check-label">No</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped show-dc-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Alergic Reactions to</th>
      <th scope="col">Yes</th>
      <th scope="col">No</th>
      <th scope="col">Notes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="a1" /></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="a2" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: As you can see there are some fields inside the table. So If someone fill-up the table data and clicks the 'No' button (which will hide the table), is there any way to clear the filed inside the table. So, when again click on the YES button visitor will see a fresh table. 
I hope you get my point on what  I want to describe.

Comment: Sure, put an event handler on the inner radio buttons and traverse the DOM to find the related `input` and call `val('')` on that to remove the value. If you need more detailed help I'd suggest starting a new question on it

Comment: Can you please check the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/63132870/13916148

Answer (score 0):

To generalize any DOM manipulation script, do not use hardcoded ids. Use methods like `closest` , `find` , `next` , `prev`. Two methods `closest` , `find` are used in this particular example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-check-inline input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Yes') {
      $(this).closest('.form-group').next('table').show();
    } else {
      $(this).closest('.form-group').next('table').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.table.table-striped {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Do you have Allergies </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="allergy" value="Yes" id="allergy-yes">
      <label class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="allergy" value="No">
      <label class="form-check-label">No</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped" id="show-dc-table">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Alergic Reactions to</th>
    <th scope="col">Yes</th>
    <th scope="col">No</th>
    <th scope="col">Notes</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```