# How to clear table data if it's hide

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have some tables which will show depending on radio button. If radio button value is 'YES' then show the table if 'No' then hide. I got the solution how to do that. Now I want to know If someone fill-up the table data and clicks the 'No' button (which will hide the table), is there any way to clear the filed inside the table. So, when again click on the YES button visitor will see a fresh table.

Here is my code:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.form-check-inline input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
        $(this).closest('.form-group').next('table').toggle(this.checked && this.value === 'Yes');
      });
    });
```

```css
.show-dc-table {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Do you have allergies?</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="allergy" value="Yes">
          <label class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="allergy" value="No">
          <label class="form-check-label">No</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped show-dc-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Alergic Reactions to</th>
          <th scope="col">Yes</th>
          <th scope="col">No</th>
          <th scope="col">Notes</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Aspirin, Ibuprofen, Codeine</td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="a1" /></td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="a2" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Do you have a cough?</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="cough" value="Yes">
          <label class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="cough" value="No">
          <label class="form-check-label">No</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped show-dc-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Alergic Reactions to</th>
          <th scope="col">Yes</th>
          <th scope="col">No</th>
          <th scope="col">Notes</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="a1" /></td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="a2" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: use the `each()` method

Comment: What do you mean, exactly when you say "clear the *field inside the table"?  Are you just looking to make the <input type="text"> values empty strings?

Comment: No, input filed and radio filed also. There will be multiple rows inside the table. Every row has 'YES/NO' radio button and a text field. just clear the values.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by clearing out the table to remove all rows, then you can use `table.html('');` where `table` is assigned `$(this).closest('.form-group').next('table')`. If you mean to just clear out the input fields, the easiest way to do that is to enclose your fields in a `<form>` and to do a form reset.

See (and run) the code snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-check-inline input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    let table = $(this).closest('.form-group').next('table');
    if (this.value === 'No') {
      $('#f').trigger('reset');
      table.hide();
    }
    else {
      table.show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.show-dc-table {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="f">
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Do you have allergies?</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="allergy" value="Yes">
      <label class="form-check-label">Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="allergy" value="No">
      <label class="form-check-label">No</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped show-dc-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Alergic Reactions to</th>
      <th scope="col">Yes</th>
      <th scope="col">No</th>
      <th scope="col">Notes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Aspirin, Ibuprofen, Codeine</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="a1" /></td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="a2" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I couldn't clear my question. The table and row will be fixed, just cleared the values. There will be multiple table rows. Every row has a 'YES/NO' radio button and text input.

Comment: See updated answer, where the fields are cleared out by doing a form reset.